# Why won't === work when I compare a bit to 1'bx in iverilog?

Tags: verilog

I am trying to setup my test-bench for iverilog so that whenever some error bit is set to "x", the module will set some string called 'state_string' to 'START', and set 'state_string' to some other value whenever the error bit is either 1'b0 or 1'b1.

I've tried to use casex for this, and I analyzed it with a waveform viewer, but I am still somewhat confused what is going on behind the scenes here. Here is the waveform that I am seeing...

**The Waveform**

[image]

My expectation is that whenever error is "x", 'state_string' will not be a series of x's.

Also, here is the code inside my testbench that is supposed to control this behavior...

```
always @(*) begin
  if (error === 1'bx) begin
    state_string = "START";
  end
  if (error === 1'b0) begin
    state_string = "RUNNING";
  end
  if (error === 1'b1) begin
    state_string = "ERROR";
  end
end
```

I understand that I could make a second bit to handle more states, but I want to either know why this way wont work, or what I can do to make this way work.

Answer (score 1):

What you have is an event driven simulator.
For the `always ( * )` to be triggered one of the signals has to change. 
Your `error` has an initial state of 'x' so it does not **change**.

Try this:

```
initial
begin
    #100;
    error = 1'b0;
    #100;
    error = 1'b1;
    #100;
    error = 1'bx;
    #100
end
```

And you will get this:
[image]